# Appending distinct records to new table Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to select records from one table, but only if they are not in a second table. Using advice other people have given, I was able to select new records using various criteria, such as name, but not index, which is what I need to use. I am unclear why this is and was hoping you could lend some insight.

Here is my code

```
SELECT table1.ID FROM table1 WHERE ((table1.ID) Not In (SELECT ID FROM table2))
```

If I replace "ID" with "name" or anything else, it works perfectly. I've already checked that the indexes in table1 and table2 match.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Is `Table1.ID` and `Table2.ID` the same data type as well?

Comment: Adding to my previous comment....  ... if they're different you'd get a `Type mismatch in expression` error, so probably not the problem.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you change the SQL to:  `SELECT Table1.ID FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID WHERE ISNULL(Table2.ID)`.  It should return the same result as you're expecting.

Comment: Your code is correct, but the solution of Darren with the left join should be the preffered solution. But anyway, just assuming: Your ID in each table is a primary key and automatically created. That means, that the same record in both tables could have different IDs in the tables. That would explain, why it works perfectly by matching by name, but not by ID. Check first, if the correspndiong records in both tables have the same ID!

Comment: What is the error or undesired results when using ID?

Comment: The undesired result was that it showed everything in table 1.I ended using Darren's solution. Even though both Table1.ID and Table2.ID were the same data type (short text and key-I mistakenly said index in my post), there are other specifications in Access, such as length. Table 1 was restricted to 8 characters and table 2 wasn't restricted. When I made the specifications the same, it worked. Thanks so much!